# resque after_dequeue hook not working, and resque workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque, worker

I am using Resque to `enqueue` jobs.

I start a worker and the jobs are processed.

My jobs extend a gem that implements job hooks like `before_enqueue`, `after_enqueue`, `before_perform`, `after_perform` and sends stuff to statsd. Those work. However, `before_dequeue` and `after_dequeue` do not seem to be called. Is there a reason why?

Also, my understanding of Resque isn't all quite there. I would call `Resque.enqueue` to queue up a job class, and then if I start a Resque worker, it will automatically pop a task from the queue and then `perform` the task. Where does `dequeue` come into play? I notice that `dequeue` destroys the the task, when does the `dequeue` step happen in the Resque worker workflow?

I want to hook into `after_dequeue` because I want to log the time that a task stays in the queue, so I need to hook into `before_enqueue` and `after_dequeue`.

Comment: Hi Raymond, did you happen to abstract the code for the enqueue / dequeue / queue time into something that could be shared? Looking to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `dequeue` is used by the client to manually `dequeue` jobs from Redis/Resque. To calculate the time a job spends in the queue, I will have to capture the time in `after_enqueue` and `before_perform`. When Resque pops a job off the queue, there is no hook that we can hook into.